# How to apply queries inside the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have very easy question, but I can't seem to figure the answer out.

I have the following table:

```
declare @Register table (Citizen  nvarchar(50), Role    nvarchar(10), Process nvarchar(10))

insert @Register values 
      ( 'A', 'seller'  , 'Process1' )
    , ( 'A', 'seller'  , 'Process1' )
    , ( 'A', 'seller'  , 'Process1' )
    , ( 'A', 'seller'  , 'Process2' )
    , ( 'A', 'buyer'   , 'Process3' )
    , ( 'A', 'seller'  , 'Process3' )
    , ( 'B', 'seller'  , 'Process3' )
    , ( 'B', 'seller'  , 'Process4' )
    , ( 'C', 'seller'  , 'Process4' )
```

I'm wondering how to extract the Citizens who interact in more than one process as a Seller and the number of different process as Seller. I want also add to the output table the ProcessNumber (for example, if a citizen was a seller in 3 different process it will generate one line for each process, in this case, 3. Showing the Process the person was involved as seller) and the Number of different process this citizen was seller (in this cited example, it'll be 3, because the citizen was a seller in 3 different process)

So the result would be:

```
    Citizen   | Process  | Number_Of_Diff_Process_as_Seller
   -----------+----------+------------------------------------
    A         | Process1 |   3
    A         | Process2 |   3
    A         | Process3 |   3
    B         | Process3 |   2
    B         | Process4 |   2
```

Comment: You description of expected out put does not match the example of output you have shown in your answer, could you change either of them to make them consistent, thank you.

Comment: I added edited my question. I'd like to get this output table I mentioned.

Comment: Still your output doesnt match your description with your provided sample data, how do you get the 2nd row in your output `A         |  2       |   3` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Citizen, a.Process, b.Number_Of_Diff_Process_as_Seller
FROM @Register a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Citizen, COUNT(DISTINCT Process) Number_Of_Diff_Process_as_Seller FROM @Register WHERE Role = 'seller' GROUP BY Citizen) b
ON a.Citizen = b.Citizen
WHERE a.Role = 'seller' AND b.Number_Of_Diff_Process_as_Seller> 1
```

Can't figure out why do you need the number of processes per citizen on each record, but I guess that's out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.Citizen,Process,Number_Of_Diff_Process_as_Seller
  from t
  join (select Citizen, count(distinct Process) as Number_Of_Diff_Process_as_Seller
          from t
          where Role = 'seller'
          group by Citizen) c
    on t.Citizen = c.Citizen
  group by t.Citizen, Process
  having Number_Of_Diff_Process_as_Seller > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `JOIN`s here.  A straight forward Analytic Function can find what you need...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        citizen,
        process,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY citizen)   AS unique_seller_process_count
    FROM
        register
    WHERE
        role = 'seller'
    GROUP BY
       citizen,
       process
)
    filtered_summary
WHERE
    unique_seller_process_count > 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53de2/2

The benefits of not having the join become more apparent the more data you have, because you only scan the data once *(instead of twice)* and don't need to re-seek rows you've already parsed, and don't need to apply a costly sort for the `DISTINCT` keyword.

That combined with an appropriate index *(shown in the sqlfiddle linked above)* mean that the Analytical Function approach is likely to be the fastest you can get for any size of data-set.

- The SQLFiddle also lets you see the execution plan
- Both plans have an `INDEX SCAN`
- Both plans have a `NESTED LOOP (INNER JOIN)`
- This solution avoids the `INDEX SEEK` *(already halving the overall cost)*
- This solution avoids the `DISTINCT SORT` *(better than halving the cost again)*

The overall cost result is that this answer's overall cost is 105.3% of an `INDEX SCAN`, where as the alternative's cost is over 550% of an index scan.